# How can I get the sizes of 3D std::vectors?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, vector, stl, size

I know that if I have a 2D vectors of any size of M by N,

then I can get the number of the elements in rows, M via myVector.size()

and I can thus get the number of the elements in columns, N via myVector[0].size()

but if I have a vector of 2D vectors, aka vector< vector< vector< double>>> myVector, of size say K by M by N, then how can I get the sizes K, M, and N?

Comment: Make a step outside the C++. Let me say: A 3d vector is something like: struct vect3d { float x,y,z; }; you have something more close to an array of 2d Matrix but not properly defined. You are talking about rows and columns, so I think my assumptions are correct. Well, beside the fact you should clarify why do you need this "monster", even whatever you call "2d vector" (a matrix indeed?) is not properly defined: your definition of  vector<vector<double>> doesn't imply the number of column is myVector[0].size(), as every "column" (using still your terms) can be of different size.

Comment: I want to perform clustering analysis, thus each cluster would represent a matrix but not necessarily the same dimensions, and so to collectively refer to those sets of clusters, I would need to define a vector< vector< vector< double>>> to store those matrices

Comment: I would still create a matrix class that may rely on std::vector, but at least you can control accesses to them avoiding wrong accesses to something that is supposed to be of fixed dimensions (once created). A plain vector of vector of vector it's just source of problems, I would try to avoid that. Hope this may help. After having a matrix type, A Vector<Matrix*> sounds good to me

Answer (score 2):

This works for me, and it prints 15.

```
vector< vector< vector<int> > > vec;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    vector< vector<int> > row;
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        vector<int> high;
        for (int m = 0; m < 15; m++) {
            high.push_back(i * j * m); 
        }
        row.push_back(high);
    }
    vec.push_back(row); 
}

cout << vec[0][0].size() << endl;
```

Comment: So does that mean if a 3D matrix is I by J by M, then to get those sizes, I will need to do vec.size() , vec[0].size() , and vec[0][0].size() respectively?

Comment: Well, this is a solution and the first I try, maybe there are some others better.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this helps.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::vector;

int main()
{
    vector<vector<int> > k{{1,2}, {1,2}, {1,2}};
    vector<vector<vector<int> > > k3;

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        k3.push_back(k);


    // Think of a 3D vector as an array made of K matrices N x M ...
    // This will work if the 3D vector is made out of 2D matrix of same dimensions..
    int K = k3.size(); // number of matrices
    int N = k3[0].size(); // number of rows for each matrix
    int M = k3[0][0].size(); // number of lines for each matrix

    std::cout << " k = " << K << "  n = " << N << "  m = " << M << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```